# Redux & Socket IO proxy error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, redux

I'm using the following plugin for managing my Socket IO instance in Redux:

https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io

I need to be able to initialize a socket only once my user has logged in. The plugin suggests in the documentation to setup the socket instance when the store is setup:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSocketIoMiddleware from 'redux-socket.io';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
let socketIoMiddleware = createSocketIoMiddleware(socket, "server/");

function reducer(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'message':
      return Object.assign({}, {message:action.data});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

let store = applyMiddleware(socketIoMiddleware)(createStore)(reducer);

store.subscribe(()=>{
  console.log('new client state', store.getState());
});
store.dispatch({type:'server/hello', data:'Hello!'});
```

As I couldn't setup the instance at the same time my store was setup I needed to find a way to set it later on. I found this solution in the redux-socket.io issues:

https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io/issues/13#issuecomment-256095866

Seemed like a perfect solution so I implemented it with my current store setup:

```
import {applyMiddleware,createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/___index';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

let socketIoMiddleware = null;
const proxyMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (socketIoMiddleWare !== null) {
     return socketIoMiddleware(store)(next)(action);
  }
  return next(action);
}

const middlewares = [proxyMiddleware, thunk];
const store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

The store renders fine with no errors but when I try to change anything in the stores state by clicking on a button for example I get the following error:

> socketIoMiddleWare is not defined

The above solution I found in the redux-socket.io repo seems to have worked for others so i'm not entirely sure why i'm getting this error.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `if(socketIoMiddleWare !== null) {` should be `socketIoMiddleware`. Looks like a typo

Comment: It is really like that sometimes. But this is actually good. Because you did type it and did not copy and paste.